# Does an equivalent transformation of a signal to a spectrogram image exist in which the phase information is part of the resulting image?

Tags: signal-processing, fft, conv-neural-network, spectrogram, phase

I'm working on a research project where we would like to apply convolutional neural networks to an image representation of a signal. However, it seems that if I would use a spectrogram, I would end up loosing the phase information. As a result, my question is:

Does an equivalent transformation of a signal to a spectrogram image exist in which the phase information is part of the resulting image?

Thanks a lot and have a great day,   Maxime

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrogram:

> Limitations and resynthesis
>
> From the formula above, it appears that a
>   spectrogram contains no information about the exact, or even
>   approximate, phase of the signal that it represents. For this reason,
>   it is not possible to reverse the process and generate a copy of the
>   original signal from a spectrogram.

Comment: Presumably your signal is not speech or music, where phase carries little or no information ?

Comment: Hi Paul, you are right, I am working with hardware radio signal identification.

Comment: OK - interesting - I think you might get a better response at http://dsp.stackexchange.com though - SO is really just for programming questions, whereas DSP.SE is more about DSP theory, and there are a lot of very knowledgeable people there.

Comment: Sounds good I'll try DSP.SE